# How to get description with php regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

Iam making a webcrawler and I need to extract the metadata that contains the description, this is what I did:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
preg_match('/<meta name="description" content="(.*)"/>\i', $html, $description);
$description_out = $description;
var_dump($description_out);
```

and I get this error

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '>' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webcrawler\php-web-crawler\index.php on line 21

What is the correct regular expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect. You start with a `/` delimiter and then you have an unescaped `/` in the pattern this ends the pattern and everything after it is read as modifiers.
Then your end delimiter was on the wrong way, was `\` should be `/`.

```
'/<meta name="description" content="(.*)"\/>/i',
```

Comment: That works, but there is a problem. When I do a crawler to twitter for example, that page does not contain a meta description, how can I validate that there is one or not? On the other hand, the pages to which I can crawler return the content but with this at the end "/>

Comment: I assume if there is no meta the return array is empty? I.e. count ==0?

Comment: When I try with google I get this error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webcrawler\php-web-crawler\index.php on line 24

Comment: this is my line 24: $description_out = $description[1];

Comment: Yes and that is because the array is empty. Nothing wrong. It's your code that is not checking if it is empty or not that is at fault. Never assign variables from arrays if you don't know if the data is there or not. Check first if it's empty, count is zero or isset.

Comment: so I need to put: `if($description == NULL) {
 return false
} else {
 $description_out = $description[1];
}` to validate?

Comment: An array from preg_match is never null. Use empty, count or isset. `if(isset($description[1])){ $description_out = $description[1]; }`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, instead of using a regex you might use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) with an xpath expression `/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content` to get the content attribute.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$items = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->value . "<br>";
}
```

The `$items` are of type [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) which you could loop using for example a `foreach`. The `$item` is of type [DOMAttr](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php) from which you can get the [value](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php#domattr.props.value).